# MySql Workbench: my table is not accepting the updated data.

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

my table is not accepting a change that I have made. It accepts the change to the text but it does not implement it. I changed the content of an automated email that goes out to new users, but when the email shows up, it is the old message.

The PK option in Alter Table is checked so I don't know what else it could be. Any thoughts?

Comment: What you mean `accepts the change`? Did you run the query? Did you `select` the records after `update`? Did you confirm `update` was success?

Answer (score 0):

What version of WB do you use on which platform? Try the latest version first if haven't installed it already. There should be an Apply button that allows you to actually send your changes.